# Why does Doxygen create so many empty folders?

Tags: linux, hash, filesystems, directory, doxygen

After running [Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/index.html) over my code base, it created two new directories:
`html` and `latex`.

Both contain documetnation files, as well as lots of these empty folders:

```
/html
├── d0
│   ├── d00
│   ├── d01
│   ├── d02
│   ├── d03
│   ├── d04
│   ├── d05
│   ├── d06
|   ├── ...
├── d1
│   ├── d00
│   ├── d01
│   ├── d02
│   ├── d03
│   ├── d04
│   ├── d05
│   ├── d06
|   ├── ...
```

well.. not all of them are empty.. very few have files inside.

```
│   ├── d3a
│   ├── d3b
│   │   └── solarpower_8h_source.html
│   ├── d3c
│   ├── d3d
```

What is all of this?  Some kind of directory hash table?  why?
I assume it's not Doxygen specific, so any links to the practice would be appreciated.

**EDIT:**
found it.
http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html#cfg_create_subdirs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens when `CREATE_SUBDIRS` is enabled in doxygen's configuration files. If you have a large project with tens of thousands of output files, this can help to avoid slow directory access on some file systems.